# How to build a Recursive Program in VB.NET 2008 using Textboxes, Buttons, etc

Tags: vb.net

I am learning VB.NET 2008. I have come across a situation

I want to build a recursive program like factorial of a number or fibonacci series for 1st 50 terms, using tools for Windows in VB.NET 2008. Say eg., type a number in a text box, click on a button and the output of the factorial of the number will be displayed on a Label. The inner code should be implemented in a Recursive way and not by using simple loops only.

I am not finding a proper way to solve this.

Please, help me out.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What have you try so far?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What did your searches turn up about calculating the Fibonacci series?

Comment: Picking the correct control is always important.  Visiting the nodes of a TreeView is best done with a recursive method.

Comment: Please (as others have stated) show what you have tried so far. We don't write your code for you. We help figure out what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it like that?

```
    Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim x As Integer
        Dim Fac As Integer
        x = TextBox1.Text
        Fac = 1
        For i = x To 1 Step -1
            Fac = Fac * i
        Next i
        Label1.Text = Fac
    End Sub
End Class
```

Hope That Helps

Re-Edit for better performance:

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

```
Try
    Dim x As Long = (CLng(TextBox1.Text)))
    Dim Fac As Long
    Fac = 1

    For i = x To 1 Step -1
        Fac = Fac * i
    Next i

    Label1.Text = "Factorial Number:  " & Fac
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
End Try
```

End Sub

sry i did not see it you can use it now... I tested it and max number is 20 :)

Comment: Ummm...`CLng(Clng(Clng(TextBox1.Text)))`?  Do you really want to convert the string in `TextBox1.Text` to a Long, and then convert that Long to a Long again, and then convert that (the second) Long to a Long? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function that calls itself.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Label1.Text = Factorial(CLng(TextBox1.Text))
End Sub
Function Factorial(ByVal number As Long) As Long
    If number <= 1 Then
        Return (1)
    Else
        Return number * Factorial(number - 1)
    End If
End Function
```